# ChildViewController breaks NavigationViewController in XLPagerTabStrip - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xlpagertabstrip

How can i programatically swich to child ViewControllers using XLPagertabStrip. I have a ParentViewController named Parentcontroller including three ChildViewController named Child1VC,Child2VC,Child3VC. each childviewController having tableViews,I want to move from Child1 to Child 2 when an item in table view selected.I have coded to switch from child controllers but it breaks  its NavigationViewControllers

Here, I have added the code in "didSelectRowAt" method of Child1VC follows:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
   let center = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ParentViewController") as? ParentViewController
   self.present(center!, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Added following code to viewDidAppear in ParentViewController

```
 override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
   super.viewDidAppear(true)

   self.moveToViewControllerAtIndex(1)
 }
```

It is moving to next child tab, but  it breaks NavigationViewController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is happening is your presenting the child view controllers from the parent and not the navigation controller. I think what you want to do is

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
   let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ParentViewController") as! ParentViewController
   self.navigationController!.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}
```

Also doing it this way it won't be parent/child view controllers.

Comment: Ye, I have tested that case also, but it calls twice NavigationController and move to child. We are already in navigation why should I call it again.

Comment: let center = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: ParentViewController") as? ParentViewController
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(center!, animated: true)